# How do I assign the returned query values to each Boolean?

Tags: soql, query, apex

If I have the following variables and query, how can assign the values of each field to their corresponding boolean?
The fields are Checkboxes on the 'myObj' object.

```
public with sharing class MyClass {

    Boolean one;
    Boolean two;
    Boolean three;
    Boolean four;

    public MyClass(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

        planid = stdController.getId();

        String query = 
            'SELECT one__c, two__c, three__c, four__c, FROM myObj__c WHERE ID = :planid ';

    }

}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using id in the where clause your query will return only a single record. In that case you case execute the query using database.query() method and assign the variables.

```
public with sharing class MyClass {

    Boolean one;
    Boolean two;
    Boolean three;
    Boolean four;

    public MyClass(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

        planid = stdController.getId();

        String query = 'SELECT one__c, two__c, three__c, four__c, FROM myObj__c WHERE ID = :planid limit 1';

        myObj__c obj = database.query(query);
        one = obj.one__c;
        two = obj.two__c;
        three = obj.three__c;
        four = obj.four__c;

    }

}
```

I have added a LIMIT statement to the soql. This way you can assign the result to a single variable. For further understanding, you can also refer the below link:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_soql.htm

Answer (score 7):

One way of doing this to define the sObject as a class level variable and access the object fields wherever required instead of separate variables.

```
public with sharing class MyClass {

    public myObj__c myObj {get; set; }

    public MyClass(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

        planid = stdController.getId();

        myObj = [SELECT one__c, two__c, three__c, four__c, FROM myObj__c WHERE ID = :planid  limit 1];

    }

}
```

then you can directly access `myObj.one__c , myObj.two__c` etc.. wherever you need it.

Answer (score 3):

Query for the record & assign from there:

```
List<MyObj__c> myObList = database.query(query);

MyObj__c myObj = new MyObj__c();

if (!myObList.isEmpty()) {

    myObj = myObList[0];
}

one = myObj.One__c;
two = myObj.Two__c;
three = myObj.Three__c;
four = myObj.Four__c;
```